# Run script step by step in R

Tags: r

I need to translate a script from R to Matlab, I have used Matlab so I have a good understanding of how it works, however, I'm new at R and one of the main obstacles I have reached so far is when I run the code.

In Matlab, after a breakpoint is established is possible to run the rest of the script step by step and when a function is reached is also possible to see what is going on -also step by step- inside the function by using f11, is there a way I can do the same in R? In order to translate the code, I need to know exactly the output of every variable and my R script have several functions inside other functions and so on. I'm using Rstudio.

Comment: You can run lines of a script in R one at a time, manually. Additionally, you can read about the functions `debug()`, `debugonce()` and `browser()`.

Comment: Im running the script one line at the time but when I reach a function how can I go inside the function also step by step?

Comment: I think you haven't read and followed through on the rest of my comment.

Comment: I've also tried using debug() on the console but doesn't work, nothing happens.

Comment: No, really, read them. You can read the help within R or in a web page, your choice: [`?debug`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/debug.html) and [`?browser`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/browser.html). The latter explicitly answering (almost word-for-word) the commented question you posed after joran suggested them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question you are not able to properly use debugger in R studio. Follow these steps:
1) Set the break point where ever you want.

2) Do Clt+Alt+R. This will make make the debugger stop at the break point.

3) If you have used MATLAB before, then you can proceed by clicking step-in, step-into and continue option.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through the documentation for `?debug` slowly. Right at the top:

> Set, unset or query the debugging flag on a function.

This, along with the usage guide just below:

```
debug(fun, text = "", condition = NULL, signature = NULL)
```

would seem to strongly suggest that `debug` acts on specific individual functions. So you would call `debug` *on* a particular function.

How would we find out what will happen when we do that? We keep reading the documentation...

> When a function flagged for debugging is entered, normal execution is suspended and the body of function is executed one statement at a time. A new browser context is initiated for each step (and the previous one destroyed).

This pretty strongly suggests it will do exactly what you asked for: execute the function one line at a time.

What if we *still* don't understand how to use `debug`? Well, if we keep scrolling down in the documentation we will find examples:

```
debug(library)
library(methods)
```

or if you only want to debug a function once:

```
debugonce(sample)
## only the first call will be debugged
sample(10, 1)
sample(10, 1)
```

(Oddly, I seem to have found a typo, which is very rare. The first `sample` is actually spelled `sampe` in my docs. Funny!)